# not everything in phpdoc header showing up

Tags: php, phpdoc, phpseclib

I'm trying to create some documentation using phpDocumentor (`phpdoc -d . -t output`) on [phpseclib's Math_BigInteger](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/master/phpseclib/Math/BigInteger.php) and had a few questions. Here's the header:

```
/**
 * Pure-PHP arbitrary precision integer arithmetic library.
 *
 * Supports base-2, base-10, base-16, and base-256 numbers.  Uses the GMP or BCMath extensions, if available,
 * and an internal implementation, otherwise.
 *
 * PHP versions 4 and 5
 *
 * {@internal (all DocBlock comments regarding implementation - such as the one that follows - refer to the 
 * {@link MATH_BIGINTEGER_MODE_INTERNAL MATH_BIGINTEGER_MODE_INTERNAL} mode)
```

Here's phpDoc's rendering:

http://www.frostjedi.com/terra/dev/phpdoc/classes/Math_BigInteger.html

As can be seen nothing after "Supports base-2, base-10, base-16, and base-256 numbers." is showing up. Any ideas as to why?

Also, I tried doing `phpdoc -pp -d . -t output` to see the internal text in the header but that's not working either. Probably for the same reason.

Here's where I'm expecting it to show up:

[image]

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Your usage looks correct, so I think that's a bug.  You can report it at http://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/issues.

Answer (score 1):

I'll repost the answer that I gave at https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/issues/804#issuecomment-17437818.

> Your File DocBlock (the one you are referring to) contains a complete explanation; while the text that you are seeing is the Class DocBlock (https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/master/phpseclib/Math/BigInteger.php#L174).
>
> At this moment the Responsive template only displays the Class DocBlock; files are not yet represented